# Tweak jQuery function to hide a div the second time you click it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hide, show

I found this jQuery plugin online that shows and hides divs. It's perfect for my site except for one factor. When you click on a heading, the corresponding div appears. But that div won't disappear until you click another heading. How do I tweak the code below so that if you click on the same heading a second time, the div hides again?

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

//default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () {
// optionally add the class .toggleDiv to each div you want to automatically close
                  $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var toggleClick = $(this);
    var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
    var isDivVisible = $(toggleDiv).is(":visible");
    $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);

    if (!isDivVisible) {
        $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
            if (options.changeText == 1) {
                $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the state of the div and show/hide accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/psLYW/1/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're trying to just toggle an element's state from visible to hidden (and back again)?

If you only want to just show/hide, jQuery's wonderful `.slideToggle()` method might be of help.

```
//  Your elements. Change these!
var link = $('.yourLink');
var target = $('.yourDiv');

//  Showing/hiding
link.click(function() {
    target.toggleSlide();
    return false;
});
```

If not, then you'll want to use the `toggle` function, with two custom callbacks for this:

```
//  Your elements. Change these!
var link = $('.yourLink');
var target = $('.yourDiv');

link.toggle(function() {
    //  Animate showing
    !target.is(':animated') && target.slideDown().text('how do you do?');
    return false; // stop the default link functionality
}, function() {
    //  Animate hiding
    !target.is(':animated') && target.slideUp().text('see you later, alligator');
    return false;
});
```

Links:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/